# Prevent arrow heads from being cropped

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to compose an arrow in SVG:

```css
svg line {
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke: black;
}
svg polyline {
    stroke: orange;
}
```

```html
<figure>
 <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="300">
    <defs>
      <marker 
        id="start"
        markerWidth="3"
        markerHeight="3"
        refX="0"
        refY="1.5"
        orient="auto"
      >
        <polyline points="1.5,0 0,1.5 1.5,3" fill="none" />
      </marker>
      <marker 
        id="end"
        markerWidth="3"
        markerHeight="3"
        refX="1.5"
        refY="1.5"
        orient="auto"
      >
        <polyline points="0,0 1.5,1.5 0,3" fill="none" />
      </marker>
    </defs>
    <line
      x1="20" y1="50" x2="20" y2="250"
      marker-start="url(#start)"
      marker-end="url(#end)" 
    />
  </svg>
</figure>
```

As you can see in this scaled-up screen-shot, it kind of works:

[image: 400% zoom]

Yet the looks differ a lot from my expectations:

[image: Expected]

Is it possible to see the complete arrow head and also get square corners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Details on how markers are rendered](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#MarkerAlgorithm):

```
overflow="visible"
```

```css
svg line {
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke: black;
}
svg polyline {
    stroke: orange;
}
```

```html
<figure>
 <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="300">
    <defs>
      <marker 
        id="start"
        markerWidth="3"
        markerHeight="3"
        refX="0"
        refY="1.5"
        orient="auto"
        overflow="visible"
      >
        <polyline points="1.5,0 0,1.5 1.5,3" fill="none" />
      </marker>
      <marker 
        id="end"
        markerWidth="3"
        markerHeight="3"
        refX="1.5"
        refY="1.5"
        orient="auto"
        overflow="visible"
      >
        <polyline points="0,0 1.5,1.5 0,3" fill="none" />
      </marker>
    </defs>
    <line
      x1="20" y1="50" x2="20" y2="250"
      marker-start="url(#start)"
      marker-end="url(#end)" 
    />
  </svg>
</figure>
```